# how to make round edges with thickness

Tags: modeling, mesh

（Sorry, my English is not good .The pictures I drew are also very poor）
I want to make the model on the right side of the picture.
I selected the top and bottom edges and use bevel . The middle is too straight

[image]

Comment: Your reference looks like  a swollen trim (raised from the face, like piping), and your drawing does not. can you say which you want?

Comment: While you're bevelling move the top and bottom bevelled edges as close together as possible, increase the number of segments with the mouse wheel to give you the curve you need. Then Shift-Alt-select just the two centre loops and use S Z 0 to move them together and M > Merge by Distance to delete the overlapping vertices.

Comment: Probably a combination of the two? Sorry, I will definitely draw clearer next time! Everyone's answers have solved my problem. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

If you have the 'Clamp Overlap' box checked, you can increase the amount of the bevel and it will stop when it meet the other bevel, giving a round edge.

You can also se the Width Type to Percent and 100%. If you put another edge loop down the middle, the bevel will reach it

Comment: Maybe there needs to be a reminder to merge duplicate vertices, where the bevels meet, one way or another.

Comment: Thank you for saving me